# Which is the best way to protect a Django API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've deployed a Django API powered with Django Rest Framework with some open endpoints and some Authenticated endpoints using Token authentication.

Which is the best way to protect the entry API allowing only to send request from the app frontend team?
I was thinking to use an Nginx basic auth, but then the **Authorization** header is duplicated, so Token auth is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the access in your API by filtering the IP address in case that the frontend team uses a static one (e.g. ALLOWED HOSTS).

Moreover, you could add the users of the frontend team in a specific group or provided the same role and filter the access by implementing a reusable custom DRF permission.

An other option could be the usage of a custom HTTP header or an API key (e.g. X-API-KEY header).